# textedit macos: after new line background color is not applied

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, textedit, macos-sonoma

In `textEdit` application in macbook ( Sonoma OS v.14.2.1), there is an ambiguity in display of background colour for same file formats rtf, rtfd. When i hit enter and move to new line, for some files background colour is applied till end of window while for some it doesn't.

[image]

[image]